# What's with the word "sardonic" in sci-fi?

Tags: isaac-asimov, larry-niven, david-brin

OK, this is going to seem to be either a ridiculous question or there is something there.

I have noticed that Asimov is a huge fan of the word "sardonic".   Maybe it's just that I notice it because I wouldn't normally use this word.   Maybe it's just that sci-fi stories lead to greater likelihood of characters being sardonic.

Am I imagining this or does Asimov really use the words "sardonic" and "sardonically" particularly frequently?

I have seen this in Niven and Brin too.    Are they also using this word a lot, and is it under influence (intentional or not) from Asimov?

Comment: I'm not sure that "I just noticed" is really evidence of a pattern. People are notorious for overly aggressive pattern "matching", and once you get started down that road the confirmation bias takes over.

Comment: @dmckee-- yes, admittedly possible, hence my caveats.  But if there's something to it, someone might be able to cite evidence.   It is not unknowable.

Comment: Generally speaking, science fiction authors have large vocabularies and are quite articulate. Asimov particularly so. He had a PhD in chemistry, and his circle of close friends were all either in academia or were authors themselves. If the word appears strange to you it doesn't mean you are dumb, but it probably means you were exposed to such at an early age.

Comment: My first thought is that writers have a 'quiver' of words which they turn to first. Authors quote themselves whether they mean to or not; Piers Anthony (yuk) continually seems to reference *very* young females finding genuine security in older male partners and the concept of "a deal under duress is meaningless" is revisited in Killobyte, the Mode series, etc. Moreover, influential artists shape the landscape of their medium. How many sax players quote Coltrane, Parker, Cannonball? It's the same with writing. In my non-answer opinion. Which I can't back up. So I won't post as an answer. So. :)

Comment: It's not just you. Both my wife and I have noticed this as well.

Comment: [I imagine fish-face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardine) whenever someone uses "sardonic"...

Comment: Timothy Zahn uses "sardonic" an awful lot. "Esoteric" as well.

Comment: This question might interest you. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153166/what-is-the-term-for-when-you-become-more-aware-of-something

Comment: To support your question: In French, many evil guy (as a James Bond villain, or a worlds conqueror/worlds crushers from sci-fi) are described as "laughing sardonically".

Comment: It’s possible Asimov was actually an alien from the planet Sardon.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Dude, YES! Every time anyone in the Empire says anything it is usually sardonically--Especially Thrawn.

Comment: I am astonished. "Sardonically," is a word I totally associate with sci-fi, so much so that the one Simpson's episode with the character "Sardonicus," stuck in my memory. The Eternal Champion in particular almost lives in this mode. 

Comment: @chiggsy I had a writing teacher that regarded "sardonic" as an abomination. Her argument was that since sarcasm is a form of irony, anyone who portmanteaus the two is just being sophomoric.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Oddly enough, you might be right. I ran a search on the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and it turns out that the word *sardonic* does indeed appear more in sci-fi than in "straight" fiction:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, *sardonic* occurs at a frequency of 3.86 per million in sci-fi/fantasy compared to 2.74 per million in general fiction. That said, the difference is really quite tiny. *Sardonic* occurs one more time per million, I very much doubt that this is in any way statistically significant.

Comment: Nice!    This is 40% difference.   I don't know how you say this is not significant.    Does your search cover "sardonically" ?

Comment: @ThePopMachine no, only _sardonic_. Where did you get the 40% from? I see 67 occurrences in general fiction versus 77 in sci-fi. The issue here is whether 67 of 476 is significantly less than 77 of 476 given that the total size of the corpus is ~10^6 words.

Comment: @terdon -Nice work. Can you narrow the search to Asimov's work specifically? How does he stack up to sci-fi/fantasy as a whole with regards to this word and it's variations?

Comment: @Morgan no idea. I am not a linguist, I just happen to know about COCA and ran a search. As far as I know, there is no way of restricting to specific authors short of downloading the entire data set and I'm not really willing to do that :)

Comment: It **is** significant as a proportion of the population: 2.74 vs 3.86.

Comment: @Pureferret is it? I am no statistician, which test did you use? Is ~3/10^6 really significantly different to ~4/10^6?

Comment: Whether 3.86 per million is significantly different from 2.74 per million depends on the sample size, and the expected variance of the quantity. Basically, if I randomly sample a million words from all of fiction, I'll find a different number of occurrences of 'sardonic' every time, the spread in number of occurrences characterizes the variance. Then you have a sub-sample (sci-fi), if the number of occurrences in sci-fi is outside the variance -> significant, otherwise, it's not. Short answer: we need more data ;)

Comment: Note that COCA is a corpus of texts from 1990-2012, so it can't tell us anything about the language of Asimov's era. I don't know if Niven and Brin were writing in that period or not.

Comment: Perhaps we should ask a sister question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Kevin I'm sure the question is already there, it's a pretty common situation to be analyzing.

Comment: Isn't the difference between ratios just the difference. So the difference is not 40% but 1.12 words per million. In other words 0.000112%.

Comment: I think to know if it was really significant you'd need to somehow figure out the average difference for all words between the genres. Or a standard deviation of difference at least.

Comment: What an age we live in that we can *actually answer* the question "is *sardonic* used more in sci-fi?" with a precise answer.

Comment: We can take the null hypothesis as being that this is Poisson distributed with the same lambda. I'm confused by the fact that apparently there are 77 occurrences within SF, and 67 in general. 77 occurrences being 3.8 out of a million means that there were about 20 million total words. If I take 2.74 as the null hypothesis lambda, then the expected number of occurrences is 2.74*20=54.8.  The p-value of seeing 77 occurrences with expected value of 54.8 is 0.0018.

Answer (score 44):

The words sardonic and sardonically were most frequently used just before the period when Asimov began writing. So I'd say he was just using the popular language of the time.

Here's a [Google Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sardonic%2C+sardonically&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csardonic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csardonically%3B%2Cc0) of the word uses.

[image: Google Ngram graph for sardonic and sardonically]

Comment: The bump in the eighties lines up with Brin pretty well.

Comment: Asa science worker who has to talk to the public ( MUch liek Asimov did ) I can assure you I often speak and smile "Sardonically" at some of the things i hear. Pretty sure that Asimov might have been the same. As to writing - Well, what's workng with using that word? The nearest synynms as cynical, sarcastic, snnerign and contemptous, all of which are overused in them selves and have more negative perceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to dig up a thread over two years old, but I created an account specifically because of this topic. I am listening to the audio book of *The Foundation Trilogy*, in which Asimov uses this word frequently and it was becoming so noticeable that I performed a Google search, which landed me here.

In the PDF I have of all three books combined, a ctrl + F search returns no fewer than 15 examples of "sardonic" or "sardonically" in the text. 7/15 in the first book and 5/15 in the third book with only two in *Foundation and Empire*. Moreover, three of those five uses were all in the final chapters, two in the same chapter. The first of the three times I felt "Of course it was sardonically" before the second time it came up I thought to myself, "Let me guess, sardonically? There it is." The third time I said it out loud with the author because you just knew that was the only possible word Asimov was going to choose, as it was also the 5th time in the book and 15th time in the series.

So, yes, there might be confirmation bias, but if an adverb is going to be used by Asimov, I would be willing to bet dollars to doughnuts that they character will be doing it sardonically.

I feel that this is also because the "voice" of these books is that of nearly every character acting like they are the smartest and most important person in the room and trying to one up whoever else is talking. I think the only reason it dips down in book two is because of all the bits with Magnifico - who isn't trying to be the smartest person in the room, and thus the surrounding characters like Beta aren't competing with him for that title; and the same goes with the traders who are as sick of the Foundation's BS as I was becoming and just want to scheme up a civil war. Once we got back to the Foundation in the second half of book three, that's where the word saw its return in full force.

Comment: Is an average usage of five times per book unusually high compared to fiction in general, though? To be clear, I'm not saying it isn't. Just that "high" is a relative term, thus you'd need to show comparative numbers from other works to say whether this is relatively high or not.

Comment: Also, this is a nitpick, but something is amiss with your numbers, because 7 + 2 + 5 = 14, not 15.

Comment: 1. You are correct, there are three in the second book, not two. That was a typo. The PDF clearly shows a 5/10 split of sardonic and sardonically.

Comment: 2. As I said, it seems to be a style choice to represent the Foundation and the attitude of its members. As the dictionary says, "mocking or cynical", which is completely how they behave to one another, always trying to one up the other in conversation with "gotcha" moments. The point is that sardonic is Asimov's go to word over the alternatives. It is "always" sardonically (15 times) and not cynically (2 times) or mockingly (1 time) or contentiously (0 times). That's why it is noticed so much. They only give twisted smiles twice out of 20 times the word twisted was used. No. Sardonic.

Comment: 3. Thank you for the edits. I will strive to do better next time.

Comment: I tend to binge on authors I like and read their books more than once. Almost all of them, even the exceptional ones, fall in love with certain words and catchphrases, and repeat them, perhaps consciously, perhaps unconsciously. A good copy editor might alert an author, but it has a lot to do with author's "voice" and how they want to be heard. If a character lives in more than one work, their vocabulary will follow them across books. The same thing is true of poets, in my experience. I write for a living and for pleasure, and I have some words and metaphors I love to use over and over.